# Number of permutations with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I'm looking for a way (formula) to calculate the number of unique ways of setting integers which have to meet specific requirements.

---

#### Examples

---

We have a set of numbers $\{1, 2, 3\}$.
What is the total number of permutations, assuming that number $1$ can only be put in the first or second position and number $2$ only in the second or third position?

**Position 1:** $1$ or $3$
**Position 2:** $1$ or $2$ or $3$
**Position 3:** $2$ or $3$

> Edit: I've already found way to solve the problem for example cases but I'm struggling with finding universal case formula.
> In this case we have $1$ or $3$ at the first position.
> For $1$, we have possibilities $123$ and $132$.
> Putting $3$ as the first number implies only $312$.
> It's overall $3$ possibilities.

---

We have a set of numbers $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$.
What is the total number of permutations, assuming that the number $1$ can only be put in the first or second position and that the number $2$ can only be placed in the second or third position.

**Position 1:** $1$ or $3$ or $4$
**Position 2:** $1$ or $2$ or $3$ or $4$
**Position 3:** $2$ or $3$ or $4$
**Position 4:** $3$ or $4$

> Edit: In this case I've started with the 4th position which can be either $3$ or $4$.  We have $3$ possibilities for each of these numbers as in previous example.    It's overall 6 possibilities.

---

#### Generally

We have a set of numbers $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$.
What is the total number of permutations where $k$ numbers have to be put either in the $p$th or $(p+1)$st position (where $1 \leq p \leq n-1$, different $p$ for each of $k$ numbers). And $s$ numbers can be put anywhere.

> Edit: I still have no idea how to generalize whole problem. I'd start from putting $s \cdot$ (ways of placing restricted numbers)

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've edited my post and added current progress.

Comment: One approach is to use the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle):  In the first example, there are $3!$ possible permutations, $2!$ permutations which violate the restriction that there cannot be a $2$ in the first position, $2!$ permutations which violate the restriction that violate the restriction that there cannot be a $1$ in the third position, and one permutation that violates both restrictions, giving $3! - 2 \cdot 2! + 1! = 3$, as you found.  For the second example, I obtain $4! - 4 \cdot 3! + 3 \cdot 2! - 0 = 6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start with a simple question: what is the total number of permutations on $[k]=\{1,2,3,\dots, k\}$ such that $i$ is in position $i$ or $i+1$ for all $i<k$.

We have $k$ possibilities:

\begin{align*}
\begin{matrix}
1&2&3&\dots&k-2&k-1&k\\
1&2&3&\dots&k-2&k&k-1\\
1&2&3&\dots&k&k-2&k-1\\
1&2&3&\dots&k-3&k-2&k-1\\
&&&&\vdots\\
1&2&k&\dots&k-3&k-2&k-1\\
1&k&2&\dots&k-3&k-2&k-1\\
k&1&2&\dots&k-3&k-2&k-1\\
\end{matrix}
\end{align*}

---

A more general problem: What is the total number of permutations on $[k]=\{1,2,3,\dots,k\}$ such that $i$ is in position $p_i$ or $p_i+1$ for all $i<k$, where $p_i=p_j$ iff $i=j$.

This is identical to the previous question; there are $k$ possibilities, since we are, in essence, just changing the labeling of the numbers.

---

The general problem: Let $[n]=\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$, and let $S\subseteq [n-1]$. What is the total number of permutations on $[n]$ such that for each $i\in S$, $i$ is in position $p_i$ or $p_i+1$, where $p_i=p_j$ iff $i=j$.

Let $\{s_1, s_2, \dots, s_k\}\subset S$, and without loss of generality, suppose $p_{s_i}<p_{s_j}$ for all $i<j$. We will call this subset *maximal* if it satisfies the following conditions:

- $p_{s_i}=p_{s_1}+i-1$
- If $s\in S\backslash \{s_1, s_2, \dots, s_k\}$, then $p_{s_1}\neq p_s+1$ and $p_s\neq p_{s_k}+1$

Since a maximal subset can be in $k$ of $k+1$ spots in a permutation of $[n]$, there are $k+1$ different possible ways for $\{s_1, s_2, \dots, s_k\}$ permute in $[n]$.

Therefore, we can partition $S$ into disjoint subsets: $S=S_1\cup S_2\cup\dots\cup S_r$, where each $S_i$ is maximal. So, the number of permutations on $[n]$ that satisfy our condition is

$$[(|S_1|+1)(|S_2|+1)\dots(|S_r|+1)]\cdot(n-|S|)!$$

The final factorial comes from the elements that were not in $S$ that are allowed to go anywhere.

---

Let's see this in action. For your second example, we have $n=4$, $S=\{1,2\}$, $p_1=1$ and $p_2=2$. Therefore, the only maximal subset of $S$ is $S$ itself. Hence, the number of permutations is

$$(|S|+1)\cdot(n-|S|)! = 3\cdot 2!=6.$$

As another example, suppose we were working with $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, and we want

- $2$ to be in position $3$ or $4$,
- $4$ to be in position $4$ or $5$,
- $5$ to be in position $1$ or $2$.

We have $n=6$, $S=\{2,4,5\}$, $p_2=3$, $p_4=4$, and $p_5=1$. So the maximal subsets of $S$ are $S_1=\{2,4\}$ and $S_2=\{5\}$. Therefore, the number of permutations is

$$(|S_1|+1)(|S_2|+1)\cdot(n-|S|)! = 3\cdot2\cdot3!=36.$$